# ajax uploader success event: unable to get json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I am using this script 
http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

for my uploader.

The uploading is great, everything works, my server side script returns a JSON upon successful upload, however, in the success event, i am not able to get the json value

```
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: site.url + 'main/upload',
    fileName: 'cpp',
    multiple: false,
    method: "POST",
    allowedTypes: "png,gif,jpg,jpeg",
    dragDrop:true,
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        if(data.error){
            //there is an error
        } else {
            //there is no error
            console.log('no errors ' + data.path);
            $('.img-thumbnail').attr('src', data.path);
        }

    },
    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
    { 
        console.log('uplaod failed');
    }
});
```

The JSON returned by my server side script is 
(as seen in firebug)

```
{"error":false,"msg":"Success","path":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/uploads\/thumb.png"}
```

However, data.path returns undefined(i use console.log to check), but when I output it with alert(data), the data seems to be intact there.
(p/s: data.error, data.msg also returns undefined value).

Is this something wrong with my logic or i am missing something out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **returnType: "json"** and

Try to use **[parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson)** like,

```
onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
{
    data=$.parseJSON(data); // yse parseJSON here
    if(data.error){
       //there is an error
    } else {
       //there is no error
       console.log('no errors ' + data.path);
       $('.img-thumbnail').attr('src', data.path);
    }
},
```

Comment: thanks, your first answer before edit gave me a clue, i went to look inside the fileupload js file and found the option "returnType: null"  which is datatype :null, so i set `returnType: "json"` and it worked. thanks.